# Concatenating strings of equal length

Tags: java, strings

My problem is this: Given two strings, append them together and return the result. However, if the strings are different lengths, omit chars from the longer `String` so it is the same length as the shorter `String`. So "Hello" and "Hi" yield "loHi". The strings may be any length. 
Is there a way to do it without using of `StringBuilder` like me:

```
public String equalConcatenation(String a, String b) {
  if(a.length() > b.length()){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(a);
    sb.delete(0, (a.length() - b.length()));
    return sb.toString() + b;
  }
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(b);
  sb.delete(0, (b.length() - a.length()));
  return a + sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not using `StringBuilder` effectively.  If you already have `sb`, then why not do `sb.append(b).toString()` instead of `sb.toString() + b`?  If you look at the generated bytecode for `sb.toString() + b`, you'll see that it actually makes another `StringBuilder` for you, like `new StringBuilder(sb.toString()).append(b).toString()`.

I would write it this way instead, with no special cases:

```
public static String equalConcatentation(String a, String b) {
    int len = Math.min(a.length(), b.length());
    return a.substring(a.length() - len) +
           b.substring(b.length() - len);
}
```

I've chosen to make it a static method because it's purely a function of the two input strings, not using any object state.